# Trouble importing tabulate in Python 3.4

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, python-3.4

I have just installed tabulate for python in order to tabulate my output in the terminal. When ever i try to import tabulate into python 3.4, it gives me an error saying

```
ImportError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

But, whenever I import it into a python2.7 console it seems to work. Can you please help me try to get this to work in python 3.4. My OS is linux.

Comment: did you install with `pip` or `pip3`?

Comment: what command did you use to install `tabulate` ? And if it was `pip` , try doing `which pip` and give th result.

Comment: i installed it with pip not pip3

Answer (score 17):

for python3 i've noticed the simple "pip3 install tabulate" does not put the lib in proper locations.

for python3:

```
python3 -m pip install tabulate
```

Answer (score 9):

ok just fixed it by intalling python-pip3, and installed tabulate via

```
pip3 install tabulate
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac using Homebrew

```
brew reinstall python-tabulate
```

may help.
I had this problem after updating `platformio`. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the cmd as admin to install tabulate,
it works for me