# Trouble importing Tabulate with Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabulate

I'm running Python 3.7 on Windows 10 and I keep getting `No module named 'tabulate'` error. I have deleted Python 2.

I've tried everything suggested in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757552/trouble-importing-tabulate-in-python-3-4):

```
>> pip install tabulate
>> pip3 install tabulate
>> python -m pip install tabulate
```

All of the above respond with

```
>> Successfully installed tabulate-0.8.6
```

If I try to run it again, I get

```
>> Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (0.8.6)
```

But I keep getting the same `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import it. What can I try still?

UPD:

I have double-checked whether old versions of Python were uninstalled, and to my surprise EVERYTHING was still there: the folders, the files, the paths in the PATH... I'm afraid that was the reason of my problems, but I won't be able to test it until later.

Comment: Try installing it into a virtualenv and see if it works in there? E.g. `virtualenv -p python3 venv && source venv/bin/activate && pip install tabulate`

Comment: The last command you're running is `python -m pip uninstall tabulate`, which appears to be an **uninstall** command. Is that a typo, or are you actually uninstalling it (which would explain your problem)?

Comment: @larsks it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by updating tabulate to the latest version using:

```
pip install --upgrade tabulate
```