# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'

Tags: tabulate

I am using Jupyter notebook system. I have already installed tabulate using cmd as pip install tabulate. The requirements are also satisfied but still getting this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9a451b8ebc97> in <module>
      1 import glob
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from tabulate import tabulate
      4 def print_helper():
      5         print()
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble importing tabulate in Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757552/trouble-importing-tabulate-in-python-3-4)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to install `tabulate` like this:

```
pip install tabulate
```